# Adding a preProcess to all methods in JS class

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck with a problem that can only be resolved if I can force some js function to run before any method in a JS class is invoked.
eg:

```
 var aClass = function() {
    function myFunc() {
        //do something
    }

    return {
       method1: function() { //do something AFTER calling myFunc
       }
       method2: function() {
           //do something AFTER calling myFunc
       }
    }
 }
```

Is there any way I can 'inject' myFunc into both method1 and method2 so it gets called before anything in these methods can get executed?

Appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your aim is to avoid repeating yourself, you could create a method called `call` which you pass the name of your method and it can call `myFunc` before calling the given method:

```
var aClass = function () {};

aClass.prototype.method1 = function () {
    console.log("Called method1");
};

aClass.prototype.call = function (method) {
    if (typeof this[method] === 'undefined') {
        throw new Error("Unknown method on aClass");
    }

    this._myFunc();
    this[method]();
};

aClass.prototype._myFunc = function () {
    console.log("Called myFunc");
};

new aClass().call('method1');

// Outputs:
// Called myFunc
// Called method1
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/se9Ya/5/

Note by adding the methods to the `prototype` rather than the actual object itself all the future 'instances' of `aClass` will share the same functions, this avoids duplicating function objects in memory.

An alternative, and perhaps better way to do this, if you want to bind an arbitrary number of functions dynamically is like so:

```
function bindPreMethodToClassMethods(klass, fn){
    var i, originalFn;

    for(i in klass.prototype){
        if(typeof klass.prototype[i] === 'function'){
            originalFn = klass.prototype[i];
            klass.prototype[i] = function() {
                fn();
                originalFn();
            }
        }
    }
}

var aClass = function () {};

aClass.prototype.method1 = function () {
    console.log("Called method1");
};

bindPreMethodToClassMethods(aClass, function(){
    console.log("Called myFunc");
});

bindPreMethodToClassMethods(aClass, function(){
    console.log("Called myOtherFunc");
});

new aClass().method1();

// Outputs:
// Called myOtherFunc
// Called myFunc
// Called method1
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gX2FN/1/

I feel the second approach is better because the semantics are more clear, you still get to call the `method1` method as normal.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This is exactly what I was looking for. I'll try to apply this to a baseClass - subClass so that a baseClass can "force" a subClass to run a preProcessor when any of the subClass methods are called.

Comment: I tried this approach in a baseClass - subClass scenario but I'm facing some issues. Can you help me understand what's going on here? I've updated the question with my new issue as well. Thanks.

Comment: @Dhananjay it might be better to create a new question. As this is a new question.

Comment: Sure.. Created new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824921/how-to-add-preprocessor-to-all-sub-class-functions